# Generic class check which properties were initialized

Tags: c#, generics

Is there a way how I can check from an instantiated class which properties were initially set?

As you can see in the example I can check for "null" value of string data type but I can't check for int value since default value is "0".

**Is there a way how I can check if a property was set at "instantiation-time" of the object?**

I would like to be able to pass any class to the "ParseProperties" class.

Check this example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // The following foreach gives me the output as follows
        // Actual output:
        // Id
        // Name
        // Age
        //
        // Desired output:
        // John
        foreach (string initiatedPropery in ParseProperties(new Person { Name = "John" }))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(initiatedPropery);
        }
        // The following foreach gives me the output as follows
        // Actual output:
        // Id
        // Age
        //
        // Desired output:
        // Id
        foreach (string initiatedPropery in ParseProperties(new Person { Id = 45 }))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(initiatedPropery);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static List<string> ParseProperties<T>(T obj)
    {
        var initiatedProperties = new List<string>();
        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            // For strings I can check if property is null but I can't check for int's if they were set. How could I do that?                
            var value = typeof(T).GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(obj, null);
            if (value != null) // --> I would need to get somehow if a property was initially set or not
            {
                initiatedProperties.Add(property.Name);
            }
        }
        return initiatedProperties;
    }

    private class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you tell the difference between an `int` that wasn't initialized and one that was initialized with a value of `0`? I don't think you are going to find a general solution to that problem without changing the class you are passing as the generic parameter (to use `int?` for example)

Comment: @MattBurland thank you for your respond. A nullable int sounds quite fair to use. I'll check that.

Comment: Object initializers are just syntactic sugar. There's no "instantiation-time" that's distinguishable from normal use of an object.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks for your comment. I know there is no "instantiation-time". However I look for a way to find out if a property was explicitely set or not.

Comment: Even `null` won't tell you whether it's been explicitly set. If I modified your first loop to `foreach (string initiatedPropery in ParseProperties(new Person { Name = null }))`, the desired output should still be `Name`, but it won't be as your `ParseProperties` method would fail to detect it had been explicitly initialised to `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a class like this:

```
private class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

There is really no way to handle this *in general* that doesn't involve some changes to the class itself. The best you could do without changing the class you are using as the generic type parameter would be something like comparing to `myProp == default(S)`, where `S` is the type of the property. This would tell you that the property *might* not have be initialized.

If you can change the classes that are being passed as generic parameters, then you have a lot more options. The simplest would be:

```
public int? Age { get; set; }
```

Now the `Age` property will be `null` rather than `0`.

Another strategy would be to have another property that will tell you if `Age` was set:

```
public bool AgeWasSet { get; private set; }
private int _age;
public int Age 
{
    get { return _age; }
    set { _age = value; AgeWasSet = true; }
}
```

And you could use some convention like *propName*WasSet as a property to identify which property is related to which (this isn't unheard of, JSON.Net for example will look for properties with the name ShouldSerialize*propName* as a way to inject some logic into serialization).

Finally, you could do something like have a base class or an interface that defines a method to give you the information you need. Something like:

```
public interface IFieldInitializationInfo
{
    string[] GetUninitializedFields();    // or maybe PropertyInfo[]
}
```

And then your classes can implement that interface and report what fields haven't be initialized according to whatever logic you want to use for *that particular class*.

Comment: thank you for your comment and the summary of the options I have. I check what I can apply in my case.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way how I can check if a property was set at "instantiation-time" of the object?

Disregarding the use of `int?` versus `int` for a "uninitialized" integer, there is no way to tell if values were set in an initializer.  An initializer is the equivalent of setting the properties after construction, so

```
Person p = new Person() {Id = 4};
```

is *exactly* the same as

```
Person p = new Person();
p.Id = 4;
```

If you *require* certain properties to be set when the object is constructed, then use a *constructor*:

```
public Person(int id)
{
   Id = id;
}
```